# VNC error: "Could not connect to session bus: Failed to connect to socket"

Tags: linux, vnc, vncserver

I started a vncserver on display :1 on an ubuntu machine. When I connect to it, I get a grey X window with an error message `Could not connect to session bus: Failed to connect to socket`.

The vnc log is:

```
Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Apr  9 2010 15:59:33
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc 


Sun Mar 20 15:33:59 2011
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
cat: /var/run/gdm/auth-for-link2-eGnVvf/database: No such file or directory
gnome-session[24880]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of DISPLAY=:1.0 environment variable: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-FhdHHIq8jt: Connection refused 
gnome-session[24880]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated environment variable: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-FhdHHIq8jt: Connection refused 
gnome-session[24880]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of SESSION_MANAGER=local/dell:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/24880,unix/dell:/tmp/.ICE-unix/24880 environment variable: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-FhdHHIq8jt: Connection refused

Sun Mar 20 15:34:10 2011
 Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::51620
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8 
 SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565
 VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565
gnome-session[24880]: Gtk-CRITICAL: gtk_main_quit: assertion `main_loops != NULL' failed
gnome-session[24880]: CRITICAL: dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name: assertion `connection != NULL' failed
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I wonder if it's because of this part: error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy ...some permissions issue, it needs to access that directory but it isn't allowed? Otherwise, every vnc problem I ever had is because A: I forgot to forward the port or enable DMZ on the router B: I forgot to set both the server and viewer to the specified port (5901 in your case) ...C: I got the wrong IP info (for example if you're connected to a wireless network, and the VNC server is running on the same network, you use the network IP address, not external.

Comment: DBus is messed up here. Reinstall it, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

try restarting messagebus service.

service messagebus restart